# How can I improve this introduction?

Tags: tone

*Hi, I'm bernk.
I'm here to make interacting with digital products a positive experience for us all.
Why are you here?*

More importantly, does it read positive or negative to you?

Comment: It sounds like it's in robotese. Nerdspeak.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm an interaction designer and this will serve as the introduction of my personal website. The audience I'm interested in is rather tech savvy so nerdspeak is perfect in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Bernk. Allow me to take you through an enthralling experience with digital product interaction.

Why are you here ?(you want to know the purpose of the other person to be present there.)
you can say "What brings you here ?"

Comment: It's interesting to see the difference of tone between the British I am and the Indian you are (first of all I thought you were American). Your approach is very good (too ??) and I am happy to approve.

Comment: The first part of your suggestion, although appreciate, doesn't work in this case. However, the "what brings you here" is a *great* suggestion! Thank you. : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm bernk. I'll help you to interact successfully with digital products.

(shorter, say at first that you will help, and there is no doubt about the success)

"Why are you here ?" is strange, a bit like "What on earth are you doing here ?" : if necessary, write rather "Tell me about you and your expectations", followed by questions.

I can't be more precise, not knowing the product, and what it offers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I wanted to get some opinions without people knowing what it's about first. I am an interaction designer, and some form of this sentence will serve as the introduction to my personal portfolio website. The audience I'm interested in is rather tech savvy so the "nerdish" aspect shouldn't be a problem.